# storing data with name of author - laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, eloquent, has-many, relation

I have hasMany relation to my model user and reports. 
I want to set author name for the reports. (Like a blog-post author)

**my model User:**

```
public function reports() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Report', 'author_id');
}
```

**model Report**

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'author_id');
}
```

**and my controller:**

```
public function create()
{
    $category = Category::lists('title','id');
    return view('dash.reports.create')->with('category', $category);
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, ['title' => 'required', ]);

    Report::create($request->all());

    Session::flash('flash_message', 'Report added!');

    return redirect('dash/reports');
}
```

I'm able to set in in phpmyadmin, but how can i set it with my controller?

**edit: my view:**

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => '/dash/reports', 'class' => 'form-horizontal']) !!}

       <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('title') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
            {!! Form::label('title', 'Servizio', ['class' => 'col-sm-3 control-label']) !!}
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                {!! Form::text('title', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required' => 'required']) !!}
                {!! $errors->first('title', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
            </div>
        </div>

       <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('title') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
            {!! Form::label('date', 'Data lavorativa', ['class' => 'col-sm-3 control-label']) !!}

            <div class="col-sm-2">
                {!! Form::selectRange('day', 1, 31, null,  ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                {!! $errors->first('day', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-2">
                {!! Form::selectMonth('month', null,  ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                {!! $errors->first('month', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-2">
                {!! Form::select('year', array('2016' => '2016', '2015' => '2015'), null,  ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                {!! $errors->first('year', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('category_id') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
            {!! Form::label('category_id', 'Cliente', ['class' => 'col-sm-3 control-label']) !!}
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                {!! Form::select('category_id', $category, null, ['class' => 'form-control'] ) !!}
                {!! $errors->first('category_id', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
            </div>
        </div>


<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-3">
        {!! Form::submit('Create', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
    </div>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: I can help but I am a bit unclear on something. Do you have unique id's for user, author and report (auto-incremented primary key)? If so it's easier.

Comment: For example, something like `DB::table('reports')->where('id', 1)->update(['author_id' => $user_id]);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very easy. Replace `Report::create...` with this.

```
$user   = Auth::user();
$report = new Report($request->all());
$report->author()->associate($user);
$report->save();
```

Make sure you `use Auth;` up at the top.

This uses the `Auth` object to get the current user,
Builds a new `Report` using the `$request` data **without** saving,
Tells the report we're associating `$user` as the `author` for the model,
Saves the report with the authorship information.

Comment: This is a much better OOP way than raw updating as per my comment :)

Comment: i try, but after press button  the browser return me blank-page
edit my post for insert the view

Comment: Could be any number of things.

Answer (score 0):

solution:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, ['title' => 'required', ]);

    $user = Auth::user()->id;
    $report = new Report($request->all());
    $report->author_id = $user;
    $report->save();

    Session::flash('flash_message', 'Report added!');

    return redirect('dash/reports');
}
```